# Why I can insert non-ascii characters into VARCHAR column and correctly get it back?

Tags: sql-server, string, unicode, encoding, collation

Below is my code sample.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (a VARCHAR(20));
INSERT  @a
        (a)
VALUES  ('中');

SELECT  *
FROM    @a;
```

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to run it. My question is, why I can insert non-ascii characters into VARCHAR column and correctly get it back? As I understand, VARCHAR type is only for ascii characters and the NVARCHAR is for unicode characters. Anyone can help to explain it please? I'm on Windows 7 with SQL Server 2014 developer edition.

Answer (score 2):

The codepage used to store the varchar data varies by DB collation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189617.aspx

Varchar is 8 bits, so you may have a different collation, or you may have gotten lucky on where your character falls on the code set

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `ASCII` and `Extended ASCII` characters below.

**ASCII**

[image]

**Extended ASCII**

[image]

I don't believe '中' is an ASCII character.

[www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't ASCII either.